# Application of command design pattern in this use case?

Tags: java, design-patterns

**Command pattern :-**  A request is wrapped under an object as command and passed to invoker object. Invoker object looks for the appropriate object which can handle this command and passes the command to the corresponding object which executes the command.

Consider a Employee management system where HR person can create/read/update/delete employee. In my career I have always designed this use case something like

```
Request from browser ->  EmployeeController -> EmployeeService -> EmployeeDao
```

EmployeeService.java  will contain all create/read/update/delete operations which will be called from controller

After reading Command pattern , I see another way of doing it where controller will work as Invoker to call appropriate CommandHandler like DeleteCommandHandler/UpdateCommandHandler/CreateCommandHandler/ViewCommandHandler

Is applying Command design pattern makes sense here ?

Answer (score 1):

Command design pattern will provide good layer of indirection and it need not be limited to only CRUD commands. May be service layer is more appropriate Invoker  as Command object can be passed through within the layer for better usage. Command object is pre-programmed with *Receiver* object (in form of your handlers) which is capable of handling request. Added advantage will be auditing (command layer actions like logging) of commands as they are invoked independent of *from where those were invoked*.

Comment: can you please elaborate on `Command design pattern will provide good layer of indirection and it need not be limited to only CRUD commands. May be service layer is more appropriate Invoker as Command object can be passed through within the layer for better usage.` ?

Comment: @emily In your design you already have service layer. This service layer is calling DAO objects directly. You can implement all _requests_ (including CRUD) as appropriate command objects. This will form a command layer which will break the direct coupling of service layer and an actual objects capable of executing it (called _Receiver_). Such a layer of indirection is very helpful in large applications. Command layer can have good control over logging commands, undo operations etc. MetaCommand can encapsulate commands within.

Comment: If I go for command patter, controller will find the appropriate commandhandler like delete command handler , similarly for edit . So there is no direct direction from controller to service but from controller to commandhandler. Right ?

Comment: @emily that depends upon what your service layer is doing. In general architectures should not cross layers (as far as possible). But yes in that case your Command layer will be in between Controller and service. Only take care not to add too much business logic in controllers, it should delegate business part to appropriate helper classes.